# Comparator in java not working

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am getting the following error when I run the code
Should i create an object of the class Mycomp in The class where this method is written

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments
```

(List). The inferred type Product is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter >

```
    public List<Product> displaySortedShoppingCart(String userName) throws ShoppingCartNotFoundException
{
    getConnection();
    ResultSet rs;
    boolean flag=false;
    List<Product> l=new ArrayList<Product>();
    String sql="select *from scart where username='"+userName+"'";
    try {
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            flag=true;
            Product pr=new Product();
            pr.setname(rs.getString(2));
            l.add(pr);
            //System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
        if(flag==false)
            throw new ShoppingCartNotFoundException();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //SortProduct sp=new SortProduct(new Product());

    Collections.sort(l);
    return l;
}
```

My Comparator implementing class is as follows

```
import java.util.Comparator;

import com.bean.Product;


public class SortProduct implements Comparator {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
    {

    Product p1=(Product)o1;

    Product p2=(Product)o2;

    int temp=p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    return temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use Collections.sort(l) where l is an object of list you are writing Collections.sort((pr) which is wrong first mistake is you have not closed bracket and other is it is not a valid paramter for method sort it should be any object which implemnts Collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: Type your Comparator as `Comparator<Product>`:

```
public class SortProduct implements Comparator<Product> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

Notice how the code is cleaner being typed - no need for casting.

Step 2: Pass an instance of your Comparator to the sort method:

```
Collections.sort(l, new SortProduct());
```

Answer (score 1):

When yousing `Collections.sort(l);` Your Product Class must implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)